# Script to set properties in a configuration file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I need to find a way to automate the settings of a configuration file. The file basically looks like this:

```
value1=hello
value2=world
value3=cookies
value4=cream
```

Ideally I would like to run a .bat file, with something like the following parameters:

setconfiguration.bat filename -value3 test -value4 success

This would then change the file data to the following:

```
value1=hello
value2=world
value3=test
value4=success
```

Is there any easy way of doing this without having to install any new tools?
Honestly I have little experience with scripting (.bat) and Google has not been very helpful so far. :(

EDIT: I found a script called repl.bat on this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/4121213
Using this I can do something like which replaces a single value. This should be able to help me out further.

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
Set "OldString=^value3=\S{1,100}"
Set "NewString=value3=test"
set file="test.txt"
for %%F in (%file%) do set outFile="%%~nFCleaned%%~xF"
pause
call repl OldString NewString e <%file% > %outfile%
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this text as a bat file, then call like: `setconfiguration.bat filename value3 test value4 success` You can put any number of value pairs.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set tmpfile="%temp%\Alterconfiguration.txt"
:loop
if x%3 equ x goto done
if exist %tmpfile% del /f %tmpfile%
set key=%2
set value=%3
rem remove any quotes from strings with spaces
set key=%key:"=%
set value=%value:"=%
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in (%1) do (
    if /i "%%a" equ "%key%" (
        echo %key%=%value%>> %tmpfile%
    ) else (
        echo %%a=%%b>> %tmpfile%
    )
)
copy %tmpfile% %1 /y
shift /2
goto loop

:done
endlocal
```

If you need to handle spaces, which I suspect you will, then you need to include the parameters in quotes. e.g. `setconfiguration.bat filename "value 3" "test a full string" value4 success`

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. I didn't expect a full and complete answer like this. Cheers!